# What's the lodash/fp equivalent of Ramda's 'when' function?

Tags: lodash, ramda.js

Looking at `lodash` and it's fp facilities., I am searching for `when` or `ifElse` equivalent.

In `Ramda`, one can use [when](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) to do semi shorthand if. Check predicate on sent data, and when true, do something. When false, return input data unchanged.

```
// truncate :: String -> String
var truncate = R.when(
  R.propSatisfies(R.gt(R.__, 10), 'length'),
  R.pipe(R.take(10), R.append('…'), R.join(''))
);
truncate('12345');         //=> '12345'
truncate('0123456789ABC'); //=> '0123456789…'
```

How this will be accomplished in `lodash`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do this in lodash/fp.  (One of these days, I swear I spend some time learning more about it!)  But do note that the version as written could well be simplified.

First, keeping it in Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors), but simplifying your functions with simple ES6-style lambdas:

```
// truncate :: String -> String
var truncate = R.when(
  s => s.length > 10,
  s => s.slice(0, 10) + '…'
);
truncate('12345');         //=> '12345'
truncate('0123456789ABC'); //=> '0123456789…'
```

I find this version extremely readable, and might leave it at that.  But you can also remove the library altogether by replacing the `when` with another ES6-lambda and using a conditional expression:

```
// truncate :: String -> String
var truncate = s => s.length > 10 ? s.slice(0, 10) + '…' : s;
```

Point-free is a great technique that can often add readability.  But there are few reasons to use it when it obscures meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In lodash fp you should 'cond' for this:

```
const showTen = fp.pipe(
    fp.slice(0, 10),
    fp.join(''),
    fp.add(fp.__, '...')
);

const gtThanTen = fp.pipe(
    fp.result('length'),
    fp.lt(10)
);

const showOnlyTen = fp.cond([
    [gtThanTen, showTen],
    [fp.stubTrue, fp.identity]
]);

showOnlyTen('12345678901');
```